# Button link not working within text-centered div

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

I got this code :

```
<div class="row-fluid text-center">
  <div class="span12">
    <img src="img/portrait.jpg"><br>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-small"><i class="icon-envelope"></i> Let's talk!</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This bootstrap button link doesn't work. So I deleted the `text-center`and it works fine.
Why ? And how can I make it work without getting it out of any `text-center`-stylised block ?

Comment: Can you show what your CSS looks like for `row-fluid`, `text-center`, `btn` and `btn-small`? With an `href` of `#`, what's reacting to the click?

Comment: I didn't overwrite these classes. These are the original bootstrap CSS classes. I didn't catch your last question... Anyway, even with a `#`, it should react (it does when I remove the `text-center` style of the `div`).

Comment: With just a `#` the only reaction will come if the click event is assigned to a handler. But it is a bit of a puzzle why removing a class would cause it to react.

Comment: Something went wrong with an icon typography I set 800%. Everything is fine now. Thank you for your time @mbratch.